# turning on / off environment variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

I have been trying to set the `$PATH` environment variable to point to different paths as I need them, but I have run into some issues.

The main thing is that when I set the PATH to point to my service that I need, I want it to stay that way in all subsequent bash shells. That is, when I open another bash shell it will be set there as well, until I decide to switch it back.  And when I switch the PATH back to its original value. I want it to stay that way.

I added a small script to my .bashrc, I also tried doing a separate script that will change environment variables. But the problem stays: If I open a new bash shell, it inherits the default environment variables and the default PATH.

I am setting those to enable the use of a daemon service. I tried turning on/off the service itself. That does not work because the paths have to be changed or else the shell would try to use those environment paths, but the service being off it will just hang.

I tried running a small C program wrapper to do those things but I ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for environment variable to exist across shell sessions you will need to place those variables into a shell configuration file. This is usually done in either `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` (if you are using Bash). For example, in my `~/.profile` file I have:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

I can add to that path as much as I want. The `$PATH` variable at the end will append whatever is current in the path.

If you need scripts to be able to access the variables, you should put the `PATH` into the `.bashrc` file. ([what is the difference between .bashrc and .profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile))

If you make a change to one of your shell configuration files, the changes will not be in effect until those files are used again. Those files are only used when the shell is first initialized. In order to make changes take effect, you need to log out and back in, or open a new shell and close the old, or `source` the file that you made changes to.

```
$ vim ~/.bashrc (edit the file)
$ source ~/.bashrc (then reinitialize the shell with the file)
```

If you only need a variable to be available in the current shell and any subprocesses, using `export` would be all you need.

Comment: Thank You! You gave me an idea, I had a script that will change the PATH as needed but only in the currently running shell. As you said, I can modify that script to change the current shell PATH variable and to go and change it in the .bashrc as well. This way when I run for example $ ./changemypath   and it will change it to what I want in the current shell I work with and in all subsequent shells that I open.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be interested in this snippet. It reloads the `.bashrc` in *any* shell, whenever it is modified. (After re-editing the `.bashrc` file, press  (or run a command) to cause the new `.bashrc` to be reloaded.)

```
# Make sure our version of the .bashrc file is up-to-date, or reload it.
chk_bashrc_timestamp () {
    if [[ "$_BASHRC_TIMESTAMP" -lt "$(get_file_timestamp "$HOME/.bashrc")" ]]; then
        echo >&2 "Reloading .bashrc..."
        . ~/.bashrc
    fi
}
_BASHRC_TIMESTAMP=$(date +%s)

PROMPT_COMMAND=chk_bashrc_timestamp
```

The only difficulty is, you must not use `$PATH` in the definition of `PATH`, or it will repeat the whole `PATH` each time it is needed:

Use

```
SYSPATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin"
PATH="$HOME/bin:$SYSPATH:/opt/mystuff"
```

instead of

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:/opt/mystuff"
```

I have used this with much satisfaction in my own `.bashrc`, except that I have protected my `PATH` from reloading each time by setting it in an `if` statement. (You may find you have other things you need to protect this way.)

```
if _BASHRC_WAS_RUN 2>/dev/null; then
    :;
else    # Stuff that only needs to run the first time we source .bashrc.
        # Useful to allow resourcing new changes
    export PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.cabal/bin: ..."
    alias _BASHRC_WAS_RUN=true
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! These environment vars gave me lots of hard times.

Comment: No problem. I usually work with a *lot* of shells simultaneously (>10), so it's almost necessary for me to go to this extreme.